# Can the computer respond to the interrupt after the first instruction is executed after the computer is turned on?

Tags: embedded, hardware, ram, bios, rom

We know that at the completion of the ***Execute Cycle***, a test is made to determine whether any enabled interrupt has occurred or not. If an enabled interrupt has occurred then ***Interrupt Cycle*** occurs. So can the computer respond to the interrupt after the first instruction is executed after the computer is turned on?

Comment: for ISR to work right at power-on we would need to have hard-coded vector table with OTP code residing inside CPU. Also CPU would need to have some ammount of built-in RAM for the stack to track nested interrupts. Consumer based CPUs do not have such built-in features so it is technically impossible to implement ready to fire ISRs. For these reasons CPUs are initialized with interrupts masked so answer to your question is - NO, computers can't respond to the interrupts after execution of first instruction on power on.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny This is tagged "embedded" and most MCU's have on-chip flash memory and SRAM., and a non-maskable interrupt that could be active on start-up.  Either way you have answered the question in a comment which is bad form - post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible; if unlikely and perhaps not on all architectures.

On ARM Cortex-M for example, the start of the vector table includes the execution start address and the initial stack-pointer - these are loaded to the program-counter (PC) and stack-pointer (SP) registers on start-up and execution starts at PC.  At this point the NVIC will not be initialised and interrupts will not be enabled, however it remains possible for a *non-maskable interrupt* (NMI) or an processor *exception* to occur that will invoke whatever handler is specified in the vector table.

For an exception handle to be invoked, your "*first instruction*" would itself have to be invalid.  And if you have an NMI occurring that early; your system is possibly broken or poorly designed. The occurrence of an NMI in any case is normally to indicate some critical error external to the processor.